# why my menu icon not showing in toolbar, just show blank toolbar

Tags: android

i try to add icon menu in toolbar. but my icon not showing. here my code. only show blank header. can someone help me...

this fragment class

```
package com.example.bams.task.fragments;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.bams.task.R;

/**
 * Created by jack on 19/02/2017.
 */

public class AddProjectFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_project, container,false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        //menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.header, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
}
```

this is my custom toolbar layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBgFragment"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorBgFragment">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my menu icon

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/backBtn"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_back_filled"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="back"/>
</menu>
```

can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Which theme are you setting for your app or this fragment? also add screenshot.

Comment: i change <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> to <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class AddProjectFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_project, container,false);

        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.header, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually to include a action bar in fragment.Remove the on menu function and put relative layout inside your toolbar in layout.Inside this relative layout adda imageview with he appropriate position that you want.You are getting a blank space because of the empty toolbar area.Adding view inside it will show the image you want to show.

Comment: Did you remove toolvar from layout?